Flutter - combine Navigator pop and pushNamed
I want to add a simple feature in my flutter app :
   Future<dynamic> showTextFieldDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DemoRegisterDialog();
      },
    );
  }

This dialog returns a custom widget that contains a button that returns this when clicked :
                          onPressed: () async {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            await _authService.loginUser(context);
                            if (_firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
                              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainPage.id);
                              });
                            }
                          };

So the idea here is quite simple : when the button is clicked, it should close the dialog, trigger the login, and then navigate to the next screen if the login is successful.
But I keep getting this error :
external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)

The login function works fine, the issue comes from the combination of Navigator.pop(context); and Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainPage.id);
If I remove one them, it's working fine.
I tried to delay the navigation, tried different types of navigators but keep getting this error.
What Am I missing here ?

showDialog is future method, so you can use then() to wait until the dialog closes. Write stuff inside then() function which runs after dialog is closed.
Future<dynamic> showTextFieldDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return DemoRegisterDialog(
      /// Custom widget's button press event
      onPressed: (){
         Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    );
  },
).then((){
   /// Show a loading indicator so the user can recognize that something is happening I have to wait
   await _authService.loginUser(
     if (_firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
           Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainPage.id);
        });
    }
});

}
You can also pass value in pop(context,VALUE) and retrieve inside then((VALUE){}); and check conditions if needed.
